# NOT A VALID MONTH ERROR IN ORACLE FOR BELOW CODE

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, query-optimization, where-clause

I am getting 'not a valid month' error for the following code:

```
SELECT last_name, employee_id, hire_date
FROM employees
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(hire_date, 'DD-MON-RR')) > 1998
ORDER BY hire_date;
```

Comment: What data type is `hire_date`?

Comment: @TBose you should never, ever use `to_date()` on something that is already of DATE datatype, as I suspect you're doing here. When you do so, Oracle does: `to_date(to_char(<DATE value>, <NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter value>), <supplied format, or if none supplied, NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter value>)`. Don't ever do that, because you could have conflicting formats between the implicit conversion (as you have here), you could lose information or get the wrong information back, and you're forcing the database to do more work than is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is the `employees` table from Oracle's tutorial, `hire_date` is already a `date` column. You don't need to use `to_date` on it:

```sql
SELECT   last_name, employee_id, hire_date
FROM     employees
WHERE    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM hire_date) > 1998
ORDER BY hire_date;
```

Comment: @mohdatif in the original snippet, the date is implicitly converted to a string using the database's default date format, and then explicitly to a date with the `to_date` call. If the default date format doesn't match the explicit format specified in the `to_date` call, you'll get this error

Comment: I have added a query from Oracle live with to_date

Comment: In addition to the comments about never, ever using to_date on a column that is already a DATE data type, you should not be using the RR format mask.  That was meant as a _temporary_ band-aid for the Y2k bug.  Twenty years later we should not still be using temporary fixes.  And _certainly_ not the 2-digit form.

Answer (score 4):

I don’t see the point for using `extract()` here. It is suboptimal, because the database needs to apply the function to *all values* in the column before it is able to filter. I would recommend direct filtering against a literal date:

```
where hire_date >= date '1999-01-01'
```

This predicate would take advantage of an index on `hire_date`. You can even add more columns to the index to entirely cover the query like: `(hire_date, last_name, employee_id)`.